# Send file names as argument to a bash script to execute the condition for every filename

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list files which uses /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out} as argument to the script myscript.sh.
The script is supposed to see if file exists, file is readable and writable and pick each file and do encryption. But the script stops after encrypting the first file.
ex: it encrypts file1.csv to file1.csv.gpg and stops. It don't pick up the files next in the path.

```
usr/bin/gpg --batch --yes -r 'keyname' --trust-model always --encrypt-files /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}
```

This works fine and encrypts all the files but fails if the file belongs to other user or group as current user don't have permissions.

So i have written script to evaluate if file exists, file is readable and writable.

```
FILE=$1
    if [ -e $FILE ]
        then
            echo "File exits"
                if [[ -r $FILE && -w $FILE ]]
                    then
                                usr/bin/gpg --batch --yes -r 'keyname' --trust-model always --encrypt-files $FILE
                            echo "Encryption Successful"
                    else
                            echo "File not accessible"
                fi
        else
            echo "File doesn't exits"
    fi
```

Script should successfully encrypt all the files in the /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}

Comment: `/test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}` is not a regex.

Comment: Your script only examines its first argument (`FILE=$1`). It ignores the rest of the command line.

Comment: i am sending the argument $1 as myscript.sh /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}

Comment: No, you're not. Did you even look at what `$1` is?

Comment: $1 is the first argument after the script name. Here i am trying to execute it as myscript.sh /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}

Comment: `/test/files*.{...}` is expanded to a number of arguments before `myscript.sh` runs.

Comment: Try: `echo /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out}` and you will see actual arguments of your script.

Comment: yes it echo's all the extensions csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out. The script picks up first argument which csv and process it. So i have to give all the arguments here like $1$2$3..so on.

Comment: Look at the `shift` command for example here: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/shift.htm

Comment: Or, in single line using `find` command: `find /test/files/*.{csv,xls,xlsx,gz,zip,tar,txt,dtxt,error,log,out} -exec gpg --batch --yes -r 'keyname' --trust-model always --encrypt-files {} \;`

Comment: You shouldn't even reference `$1` or `$2` at all.  If you want to iterate over all the arguments, use a basic `for` loop. `for arg; do ...; done`

Comment: Don't bother checking if the file exists and is writable.  (Even if the check succeeds, that status is out of date by the time you run a command.) . Just do `for FILE; do /usr/bin/gpg ... "$FILE" ; done`.  The entire script is practically a one-liner.

Comment: I need to check for file exits and writable. If i don't do this then i will get "permission denied" error for other users files.

Comment: resolved with for loop. Thanks